# Different behaviors of java scripts toLocaleTimeString in Chrome and other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Repro method:
1. Please change the p.c.’s time zone to “(UTC+2) E.Eurpe”, 
2. Open IE and Chrome, in the JS console, type:

(new Date(2015,4,7,16,07,0)).toLocaleTimeString("en", {hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", hour12: true});

Chrome return 3:07PM and IE return 4:07PM

Anyone knows why and how to fix it? Thanks. Other time-zone seems good.

Comment: what version of IE were you using and in what time zone your PC is originally in?

Answer (score 0):

There's a huge possibility that your browser does not support the locales and options argument of the toLocaleTimeString() method.

As per documentation in MSDN and MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Browser_compatibility

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/474de325(v=vs.94).aspx

> The locales and options parameters are not supported in all document
>   modes and browser versions

Try to check for the locales and options support first using this [code snippet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Example:_Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments)